# Jquery reading several array parameters from url

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, urldecode

I have the following URL:

```
http://mydomain/Forwards?searchValue[]=Nike+Webstore&searchValue[]=Bodyman&category_filter[]=Animals+%26+Pet+Supplies&category_filter[]=Fashion&country_filter[]=Aland+Islands&country_filter[]=American+Samoa
```

This url contains alot of paramters that are sent as an array:

Now i wish to get each individual array and its value out

in the above example the result should be something like this:

```
searchValue = array(
[0] = 'Nike Webstore'
[1] = 'Bodyman'
);

category_filter = array(
[0] = 'Animals & Pet Supplies'
[1] = 'Fashion'
);

country_filter = array(
[0] = 'Aland Islands'
[1] = 'American Samoa'
);
```

is it possible to get it out like this and if so how? i have attempted with the following:

```
 decodeURIComponent(
    (RegExp(name + '=' + '(.+?)(&|$)').exec(location.search)||[,null])[1]
```

However this only returned 1 value  (Nike Webstore) in my example.

Comment: i just made a quick code that does what you are trying to do.... but i havent tested it.. try changing the variable " url " and see if it works... here is the link...  http://jsbin.com/UYILAzU/2/edit?js,console

Comment: @PsychHalf il test it hang on :D

Comment: okay.. so how did the test go??

Comment: @PsychHalf just finished it when perfect can you post it as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as parameters are an array. the below code will work just fine..

```
// our test url
var url ="http://mydomain/Forwards?searchValue[]=Nike+Webstore&searchValue[]=Bodyman&category_filter[]=Animals+%26+Pet+Supplies&category_filter[]=Fashion&country_filter[]=Aland+Islands&country_filter[]=American+Samoa" ;
// filtering the string..
var paramsList = url.slice(url.indexOf("?")+1,url.length) ;
var filteredList =  paramsList.split("&") ;

// an object to store arrays
var objArr = {} ;

// the below loop is obvious... we just remove the [] and +.. and split into pair of key and value.. and store as an array...
for (var i=0, l=filteredList.length; i <l; i +=1 ) {
  var param = decodeURIComponent(filteredList[i].replace("[]","")).replace(/\+/g," ") ;
  var pair = param.split("=") ;
  if(!objArr[pair[0]]) {  objArr[pair[0]] = [] ;}
  objArr[pair[0]].push(pair[1]);
}

console.log(objArr);
```

which will give us....

```
[object Object] {
  category_filter: ["Animals & Pet Supplies", "Fashion"],
  country_filter: ["Aland Islands", "American Samoa"],
  searchValue: ["Nike Webstore", "Bodyman"]
}
```

hope this helps.. :D

Answer (score 1):

Try to see if this pattern works for you

```
(?:\?|&)(.+?)=([A-Z+%0-9]+)
```

[Example here](http://regex101.com/r/vH5fP5)