# Anchor Link to Multiple Locations using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm currently working with this piece of code:

**Fiddle:**
http://jsfiddle.net/2hmzcgqm/12/

Right now I can use `#rugby` to be taken to a certain `span` within the Accordion.

I'd like to be able to extend this to use `#football` also. Can someone help? :-)

**Javascript:**

```
(function($) {
    var allPanels = $('.accordion > dd').hide();
    var allLinks = $('a.heading');
    $('.accordion > dt > a').click(function() {
        allPanels.slideUp();

        //Remove all 
        allLinks.removeClass('active');

        if ($(this).parent().next().is(":visible")) return false;
        $(this).parent().next().slideDown();

        //Add active class
        $(this).addClass('active');

        return false;
    });
    //$('.accordion > dt > a').first().trigger('click');

    function setAccordion() {
        // Get id from url
        // var url = window.location.pathname;
        // Test url
        var url = 'localhost:58000/gallery#rugby';
        var id = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('#')); // This will give you #football
        var spanTag = $('.accordion').find(id); //#football span tag
        var parentTag = spanTag.closest('dd');

        //open the accordion
        allPanels.slideUp();
        parentTag.slideDown(); 
        parentTag.prev('dt').find('a.heading').addClass('active');
    }

    // Call the function
    setAccordion();
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Can you explain what your intended goal is. There is no question at the moment, and your aim is not clear.

Comment: He uses a accordion and using params in the url he wants to open the correct accordion. It is working for 1 tag ( eg rugby or football ) but now he wants the possibility to open rugby and football accordions

Comment: VDesign is correct. I'd like to use multiple parameters, so `gallery#basketball` or `gallery#rugby` etc :)

Comment: @michaelmcgurk it would also be nice to try something your self. Only then you can fully understand what the code is doing. Search in google to catch multiple url params and loop trough them to set the accordion.

Comment: Why do I have a deja-vu with this question?

Comment: Probably because I already asked the question earlier today :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all we can't write full code for you, that's not the point of Stackoverflow.
However we can help you out to search in the right direction.

If you want multiple elements to define in your url you can see the following example [Jquery reading several array parameters from url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19377617/jquery-reading-several-array-parameters-from-url)

Then catch the params from the url and create an array which you then iterate over to open or set the correct accordion item.

```
var arrayParams = [];
$.each(arrayParams, function(key, value) {

    // Get every item from the url and open the correct accordion item

});
```